# Why was the base_fee for the routing fee calculation of the Lightning Network included?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-routing, lightning-rfc, lightning-fees

Currently and [as defined by BOLT 07](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/07-routing-gossip.md#htlc-fees) on the Lightning Network, the fees for forwarding an HTLC of amount `amount_to_forward` are computed as:

```
fee_base_msat +  amount_to_forward * fee_proportional_millionths / 1000000
```

I am wondering why the `fee_base_msat` was actually included and which concrete problem it solved that could not be solved if the `fee_base_msat` were dropped?

Comment: What about the other way around? Which concrete problem did adding a proportional fee solve that could not be solved if it were dropped? For me it seems its all about profitability not about using the network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was added as a compromise against *more complicated* ideas, actually. Base plus percentage is a pretty standard fee structure, so I went with it.

If I'd been more familiar with the finance world, it would have been expressed in basis points, though, not ppm.